# String column contains exact matching words through spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes, the first contains the actual data (Read from CSV file), and the second contains one column with multiple keywords.
i.e Dataframe-1 look-alike below (Where we have to search):

[image: ID Name Text 1 test1]

Dataframe-2:

[image]

Output Which I want:

[image]

I am using spark scala here. I want an exact word match from dataframe-2 in dataframe-1. I have used function such as like, rlike, contains but it is not giving me the output which I want. Can anyone know how to develop this logic in spark scala SQL or using spark scala functions of dataframe. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two DataFrames on a `Regex` condition via [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@regexp_replace(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,pattern:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,replacement:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), as shown below:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (1, "Test1", "Amount paid to User1 dt"),
  (2, "Test2", "Amount paid to User1 dt"),
  (3, "Test3", "Amount paid to balamurugan dt"),
  (4, "Test4", "Amount paid to final dt"),
  (5, "Test5", "Amount paid to John less dt")
).toDF("ID", "Name", "Text")

val df2 = Seq("User1", "murugan", "Amo").toDF("Text")

val pattern = concat(lit("\\b"), df2("Text"), lit("\\b"))

df1.join(df2, regexp_replace(df1("Text"), pattern, lit("")) =!= df1("Text")).show
// +---+-----+-----------------------+-----+
// |ID |Name |Text                   |Text |
// +---+-----+-----------------------+-----+
// |1  |Test1|Amount paid to User1 dt|User1|
// |2  |Test2|Amount paid to User1 dt|User1|
// +---+-----+-----------------------+-----+
```

Note that `\b` represents a word boundary, thus limiting the Regex match to word match only.

---

UPDATE:

As suggested in other answers, `left_semi` join would probably work better so as to avoid duplicated rows when there are multiple matches.  The default `inner` join would be suitable in case `df2` has columns to be included in the result dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left semi join based on the condition that df1 text contains the strings in df2 text with a space before and after the words:

```
val result = df1.as("df1").join(
    df2.as("df2"),
    expr("df1.text rlike concat(' ', df2.text, ' ')"),
    "left_semi"
)

result.show(false)
+---+-----+-----------------------+
|ID |Name |Text                   |
+---+-----+-----------------------+
|1  |Test1|Amount paid to User1 dt|
|2  |Test2|Amount paid to User1 dt|
+---+-----+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `Text` column in df1 into an array of words and join using `array_contains` function :

```
val df3 = df1.alias("df1")
  .join(
    df2.alias("df2"),
    array_contains(split(col("df1.Text"), "\\s"), col("df2.Text")),
    "left_semi"
  )

df3.show(false)

//+---+-----+-----------------------+
//|ID |Name |Text                   |
//+---+-----+-----------------------+
//|1  |Test1|Amount paid to User1 dt|
//|2  |Test2|Amount paid to User1 dt|
//+---+-----+-----------------------+
```

Comment: `split` probably won't work if the string to be matched has white spaces (e.g. "paid to").

Comment: @LeoC agree. and probably not the best solution too but wanted to show another way of doing at least for single-word keywords :)